# What are the rules for green blocks decay in Antichamber?

Tags: antichamber

What are exact rules for green blocks decay in Antichamber?

When you have a chain of green blocks and take one in a middle some part (or all of it) of it will decay. How can you predict which part is it?
Is there a special rule for the situation when you remove one block, chain begin to dacay and meanwhile you remove another block?

I see that if I have straight line of green blocks and remove one then the longest part will remain present (if parts are equal all will decay). But when the chain is not straight the behaviour looks unpredictable for me..

Answer (score 4):

Your observation that the longer part of a straight line survives is the important observation. Technically, any section which is *at least half the volume of the original structure* will survive. This is important in a couple of rooms: if you can break a structure into 3 or 4 parts with a single block removal, usually all of the parts will vanish.